# PHP Modify content of file before is included

Tags: php, html, require

Is possible to somehow modify the content of file that is being included in the existing code by `require` function? For example I am including file in my code like this:

```
require $page_body;
```

Now I want to omit the HTML tags using the `strip_tags` function to get rid of HTML tags. 
If this code contains pure HTML tags without PHP code (`<?php /* php code goes here */ ?>`) the following works as expected:

```
  $content =  strip_tags(file_get_contents($page_body));
  echo $content;
```

But if my `$page_body` is mixture of HTML and PHP the echo returns nothing, when I've printed `$content` using `print_r` it seems like several empty strings

```
[wakatana@HP-PC v2]$ php includer.php 













[wakatana@HP-PC v2]$
```

My guess is that `strip_tags` did not works well with HTML code where alos PHP is included.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), I suggest you check it out, can be useful for other stuff too.

```
ob_start();
require $page_body;
$content = ob_get_clean();
echo strip_tags($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use require or include, the code is inserted inside the file, after that you cant change it.

What you can do is open the file with fopen() and then do all the changes and save the file. After all that, when you load the file again it will be as you wanted it to.

If you don't want to change the actual file, you can open the original, as well as a temporary file, copy information from original, change it, save it to temporary file, include the temporary file and then delete it. This way you will have the original information changed the way you like without changing the original file.